# proving a set is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{3\times 3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am working through some homework problems and I ran into one that I am not sure where to start,

Is the following set a subspace of $\Bbb R^{3\times 3}?$

$$\left\{A\in\Bbb R^{3\times 3}\,\middle|\,\dim(\operatorname{null}A)=2\right\}$$

I know that since the dimension of the null space of $A$ is $2$, $A$ must only contain $2$ pivot elements, meaning one row of $A$ is a zero vector.  Where do I go from here?

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The claim that one of the rows of $A$ is the zero vector is incorrect. It merely means one of the rows is linearly dependent on the other two. This can happen in many ways without any zero entries in the matrix at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Does the null matrix belong to your set?

Comment: No because the dimension of the null matrix is zero, which isn't in A, and since the null matrix of M3x3 isn't in A, A is not a subspace.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the hint and not the exact answer!

Comment: @JohnSayle more accurately the dimension of the null space of the null matrix is $9$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Sure. Thank you for correcting me.